# Receive streaming data from dataset with custom receiver [Spark Streaming]

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, apache-spark-dataset

I am new with `Spark` and it's librabries!

I have a case where I need to send a dataset to `store()` of custom receiver, then streaming data from this custom receiver.

I am getting a dataset in this way inside custom receiver class:

```
Dataset<Row> jdbcDF = spark.read()
.format("jdbc")
.option("url", "jdbc:mysql:dbserver")
.option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
.option("user", "username")
.option("password", "password")
.load();
```

Now I want to use this dataset as streaming data, so I have to store this dataset in `store()` of Receiver class:

```
store(jdbcDF);
```

Is it possible to streaming in this way?

**p.s** not using `Structured Streaming Programming`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you find some solution about?

Answer (score 1):

spark does not support streaming of a jdbc database table. but it does support as a receiver. Rather use a kafka connect to send your data from a DB table as a streaming service and read it via spark structured straming.